# Vertical align a text to the middle of a button that includes a full heigh image to send as email

Tags: css, html-email

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but the solutions don't seem to work.

I think that's because the button includes an image with `style="height:100%;"` (but I'm not sure)

Note: the button is to use on an email, so I'd say it's better to use inline css.

My last attempt has been including a span within the button for the text only:

```html
<button style="height:100px; font-size:24px; color:white; background-color: #4CAF50; "><img style="height:100%;" src="https://i.imgur.com/XcXLJBA.png"> <span style="margin-bottom: 20px; line-height: 150px;">Send WhatsApp</span></button>
```

The output is this:

[image: output button]

I've also tried to add to several places (with no result): `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;`

I've not more ideas. How to center that text vertically to the center?

Comment: `img,span {vertical-align:middle; }` there must be dozens of duplicate of that kind here ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus agreed :)

Comment: I don't think flex will work well with emails. I think a lot of emails won't be able to interpret it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to demonstrate my earlier comment

```css
img,span {vertical-align:middle; }
```

```html
<button style="height:100px; font-size:24px; color:white; background-color: #4CAF50; "><img style="height:100%;" src="https://i.imgur.com/XcXLJBA.png"> <span >Send WhatsApp</span></button>
```

Comment: I would swear that I also have tried `vertical-align:middle;` !! I guess I didn't in the correct place. Weird. Thanks!!!